# Looking for a Lightweight JavaScript/PHP Spell Checker for my PHP Web Application

Tags: javascript, php

I just finished developing a PHP/JavaScript web application for preparing Quotations using PHP, jQuery, MySQL, and native JavaScript. This application requires efficient spell checking (client requirement).

### What I need

Does anyone know of any lightweight JavaScript-based or PHP-based Spell Checkers out there that work like ieSpell (pops up a screen with buttons for change misspelled word, ignore, add to personal dictionary, suggestions, etc) OR any spell checkers for the Google Chrome browser that work like ieSpell (this would satisfy Chrome users, while ieSpell satisfies IE users)?

The main requirement is that the spell checker needs to pop up, provide suggestions for misspelled word, and have the ability for user to add words to the dictionary, and it should not be an inline spell checker.

The Spell Checker is for simple textareas, no WYSIWYG/Rich-Text editors are involved.

If a paid (licensed) version of a decent spell checker that meets these requirements is available, I am willing to go for it.

### What I already tried

I have done a lot of research online, but many of the spell checkers I found are inline spell checkers which just highlight misspelled words with red squiggles and require the user to right-click and choose correct word.

- First I tried **ieSpell** for the Internet Explorer browser, which works beautifully for Internet Explorer, but is useless in Google Chrome, and some of the users of my app access it via Google Chrome.
- And then I tried **[JavaScript SpellCheck](http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/)** but this was the trial version, which caused a lot of frustration, and when I went to purchase an intranet license for it, the website no longer seems to exist.
- I even tried **PHPSpellCheck**, but it seems to be the same as JavaScript SpellCheck, directs me to [JavaScript SpellCheck](http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/) which no longer seems to exist.
- **[LPology](http://www.lpology.com/code/spellcheck/)** (JavaScript/PHP Spell Checker) would be an excellent alternative; unfortunately, it does not seem to have the ability to add words to a personal dictionary, and this is a major requirement for me.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!